# GEB find before element and check styling

Tags: css, geb

I am working on a project that is using Geb. -- I need to create a selector that hooks into the before element.

```
backgroundImageStyles(required: false) { $('.element:before')}
```

and then assess the styling

```
landingPage.heros[0].backgroundImageStyles.css("background") == '#000000'
```

this isn't working though - and I will also need to test for the background opacity - like the 0.2 in this gradient

```
background: linear-gradient(to top right, #000000 0%, rgba(3, 124, 104, 0.2) 100%);
```

Comment: something like this practical? 
    String getBackgroundPattern() {
        def url = CssUrlParser.parse(beforeElementCssProperty('div.event-hero.site-section'))
        new PathlessApplicationUnderTest(browser.baseUrl).httpClient.get(url).body.text
    }

    String beforeElementCssProperty(String propertyName) {
        js.exec(singleElement(), propertyName, """
            var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], ':before');
            return computedStyle.getPropertyValue(arguments[1]);
        """)
    }

Answer (score 1):

As you are probably aware, Geb is using Selenium WebDriver to select elements in the browser and as far as I'm aware it's not possible to select `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements using Selenium because they don't really exist in the DOM.

As a side note I'd suggest rethinking your test. I might not have the full picture and understand what exactly you are trying to test and if there is a better way to do it but in general asserting on styles in browser tests is almost never the right thing to do.